# pdflatex throws bad parameter, unable to compile anything

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, latexmk

I am getting the following error message when I try to compile anything on my system:

```
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP850, CP65001, CP1252)
I changed them all to CP1252
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 4 Apr. 2023. Version 4.80.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  --max-print-line=10000 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "d:/Archive/Bachelor/writing/Thesis/tex/main.tex"'
------------

Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\erikf\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
Latexmk: No log file was found, neither the expected one, 'main.log', nor one in '.'.
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Latexmk: Couldn't read log file 'main.log':
  No such file or directory
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'd:/Archive/Bachelor/writing/Thesis/tex/main':
   *LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'main.log'
----------------------
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (850,65001)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Run of rule 'pdflatex' gave a non-zero error code
```

when I go look at the logs this is what I find:

```
2023-05-18 17:59:50,335+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2023-05-18 17:59:50,358+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Bad parameter value.
2023-05-18 17:59:50,358+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: parameterName="save_size"
2023-05-18 17:59:50,358+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex\TeXAndFriends\TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h:107
2023-05-18 17:59:50,358+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Bad parameter value.
2023-05-18 17:59:50,358+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: parameterName="save_size"
2023-05-18 17:59:50,358+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex\TeXAndFriends\TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h
2023-05-18 17:59:50,358+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 107
2023-05-18 17:59:50,360+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (5452) finishes with exit code 1
```

Seems to refere to some C header, I am unable to find out whats happening, would love some help.
**EDIT**
Testing on basic hello-word.tex

```
\documentclas[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
HELLO_WORD
\end{document}
```

Command:

```
pdflatex hello-word.tex
```

Result:

```
Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\erikf\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
```

Log:

```
2023-05-18 18:13:49,110+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Bad parameter value.
2023-05-18 18:13:49,110+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: parameterName="save_size"
2023-05-18 18:13:49,110+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex\TeXAndFriends\TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h
2023-05-18 18:13:49,110+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 107
2023-05-18 18:13:49,114+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (31524) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: do not use a script like latexmk if you get errors. They are difficult to debug. Create a small hello-world.tex and then try to compile it on a command line with `pdflatex hello-world`

Comment: done, says that pdflatex did not succeed. Same exact error listed in the log

Comment: @Indiano That doesn't sound like a pdfTeX error at the command line: can you edit in _exactly_ what you see?

Comment: @JosephWright edited.

Comment: did you edit some configuration e.g. to increase memory or save_size? How did you install miktex?

Comment: After many attempts to solve this I reinstalled miktex fresh using the basic-miktex-23.4-x64.exe. No particular configuration, never touched pdflatex.ini in my life

Comment: still failing after your fresh installation?

Comment: yup! And in the exact same way, maybe something that has to do with perl?

Comment: perl is not involved if you only call pdflatex. It sounds like a faulty configuration file, so search in the various miktex trees (also the local ones) if there is somewhere a .ini file with a save_size setting (it can also be in texapp.ini or something like this). Or install texlive if you don't want to search ...

Comment: found it, I had a double path for the miktex installation,a wrong one in C: and one in D:. After a removed the path and did a clean reinstall everything went back to normal, thanks anyways

Comment: I had the same problem. Luckily, I have read all comments, because the root cause was exactly this again: mixed two installations (a manual installation and a different installation done using winget). Please post your comment as an answer!