# The Latex PDF is not built on vscode - Problem on Latexmk

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, vscode

I was trying to build a Latex PDF file on vscode, and it always gives me an error. But every time trying to seek out the error vscode, it eventually fails to build, giving the following error logs:

```
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\...\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
Latexmk: No log file was found, neither the expected one, 'test.log', nor one in '.'.
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Latexmk: Couldn't read log file 'test.log':
  No such file or directory
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'c:/.../test':
   *LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'test.log'
----------------------
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
```

At first it was considered as a simple compile error derived from `.tex` file, but I think it is not. However, there is literally no idea why vscode keeps failing to knit the latex PDF even for a quite simple `.tex` file, like the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

This is just a test.

\end{document}
```

I also have tried to re-install the Miktex, but could not figure out the reason why it says there is no log file on directory. Any helps will be very appreciated.

**EDIT**
The `pdflatex.log` in miktex recorded some fatal errors, which is indeed difficult to understand. Here is the entire log when trying to build `test.tex`, and every time I try to build the `tex` file it shows multiple error messages of `Bad parameter value`. What is this error actually meant by?

```
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 INFO  pdflatex - this process (35120) started by 'perl' with command line: pdflatex --max-print-line=10000 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder c:/.../test.tex
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 FATAL pdflatex.core - Bad parameter value.
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: parameterName="save_size"
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex\TeXAndFriends\TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h:107
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 FATAL pdflatex - Bad parameter value.
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 FATAL pdflatex - Info: parameterName="save_size"
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex\TeXAndFriends\TeXMFMemoryHandlerImpl.h
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 107
2023-06-05 20:26:59,654+0900 INFO  pdflatex - this process (35120) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: check the log file `C:\...\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I checked the log file and edited the question. I still have some difficulties on interpreting those warning messages.

Comment: something is wrong in the config-files of miktex.  Do you have perhaps two miktex installations?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not sure about it.. and would it be helpful if I make an uninstallation for one of those? Like, how can it be checked?

Comment: In the last comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686080/2388 it was mentioned as the reason.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hope not, because I have no D drive on my laptop. Double installing on C drive also might not make sense... I also found that in `texapp.ini` there is a parameter `save_size = 50000` and its explanation was "Space for saving values outside current group." Is there a point of modification on `ini` file?

Comment: Sorry but it is not possible to give remote advices here. The only thing I can say: investigate before you change anything (and this includes reinstalling and changing files). Try also to compile from a command line.